# Using Android with cloud endpoints and firebase

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to make an android app which would use both appengine cloud endpoints and firebase. After setting up the credential in firebase console, i went ahead to the appengine console to do the same however i encounter this error.
"Duplicate fingerprint
The fingerprint you specified is already used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project"

Is there a solution for this?